# How do I get the current records in the table when I filter?

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I'm using filament v3. I want to set action url with current records id after making filter

I tried this, but it gets only initial records and does not changing after filter

```php
->url(fn (Transaction $records) => route('transactions', ['transactionsId' => encrypt($records->pluck('id'))]))
```